# Map caps lock to control. In linux. Without X

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux, capslock

I'm trying to map caps lock to control in a terminal. X is not enabled. Distro is Arch linux. Is this possible?

Comment: You should be able to hack at the keyboard map - you can find them under `/usr/share/kbd/i386/include/linux-keys-bare.inc` and `/usr/share/kbd/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz` (on my system - depends on your architecture and keyboard layout). It goes without saying that this should be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BAM](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc5), emacs wiki has the answer. Loadkeys does the trick.

Comment: Even though this question is for "without X", the link provided gives information for all kinds of setups, and I found the easy to do Gnome instructions via this

Answer (score 4):

Just for future reference, wiki of your distro had (or now has) you covered: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KEYMAP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. In this Arch Linux [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Accents_on_US_keyboards), there's a lengthy example of remapping a keyboard with `xmodmap`. In another Arch Linux [discussion forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=129604), another user discusses his `xmodmap` configuration to disable the caps lock key. You should be able to remap your caps lock to control.

Comment: `xmodmap` won't work if X isn't enabled.

Comment: Keith Thompson is correct. I'm trying to remap without X, which is why I'm asking here - it's pretty hard to find a good resource on the net that doesn't suggest xmodmap.

Comment: Good point - overlooked the X mentioned in the question.